# Setup Webhook with Appwrite functions

Tags: next.js, stripe-payments, appwrite

Hi I'm using nextjs and Appwrite functions to make subscriptions over stripe,
and I use this appwrite: `https://github.com/stnguyen90/appwrite-templates/tree/main/node/subscriptions-with-stripe`
and my question is what I can add for webhook endpoint?
My appwrite domain: appwrite.test.rs, next is on localhost:3000
if I call from appwrite execution: /webhook errors is: `{"type":"StripeSignatureVerificationError","raw":{"message":"No stripe-signature header value was provided."},"payload":"{}"}`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to generate a custom domain (and set up the DNS records) for your function on the Domains tab of your function. Then, you can make a request to that domain to trigger the function.